# randomly failure entering BIOS

Tags: boot, bios

I am new to servers, and my task is to install Ubuntu(or any other OS) onto a new Intel server. However, I have problems turning on the server. With both power cables plugged in, the time the server take to enter the BIOS is at least 5 minutes, and in some worst cases, the server cannot enter BIOS. The VGA has no signal and the USB has no power. Even in the same environment, the result is not reproducible(That means there is always a possibility to fail).

Is it an indication of hardware program(Not likely, it is a brand new server)? Or is my faulty operations the cause? Any suggestions? thanks.

Comment: it seems to be a hardware issue, did you  tried resetting bios to default settings?

Comment: Currently I can't enter the BIOS settings of the machine. It failed to power on. And my mentor told me that the machine is using an alpha version of Intel's hardware.

Comment: failed to power on, then please check in that way, are you getting output from SMPS, check whether correct power is coming from the SMPS.if SMPS is ok, then issue will be definitely with the main board. try to remove all cards,HDD and try to boot if SMPS is ok.

Comment: How to check if I am getting enough power from SMPS? What I only know is that is fan is running and lights blinking on the motherboard. And there is two digits on the motherboard, and I don't know the meaning of them. (http://superuser.com/questions/621652/meaning-of-digit-numbers-on-motherboard)

Comment: The digits always end at 99(may be 66 on the other direction). Does it mean the process of self-check program, or does it means the fan speed? (currently the fan is spinning at full speed)

Comment: what is the model/make of the server?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9706/discussion-between-user522829-and-renju-chingath)